# Measuring short distances

Tags: distance, sensors

What's the best way to wirelessly measure the distance between two objects (computer, smartphones or a specialised device) that are a few meters apart down to a ~10cm accuracy?
Is this possible by piggybegging on WLan, bluetooth or GPS?

Comment: Since 10cm is 33 picoseconds for light (and radio), it would be hard to measure such an interval even in a well equipped physics lab, and probably impossible using consumer devices.

Comment: @msw: Uh, what? Look at any ruler.

Comment: and the wavelength of WiFi is about 12 cm so it can't resolve differences at that scale. I did look at a ruler with my 2.5GHz eyes and it disappeared ;)

Comment: @msw:
WiFi and bluetooth both have the characteristic that the signal gets weaker the farther you are from the source.

Comment: But lacking knowledge of the absolute emitted power and the specific atmospheric attenuation at this instant (neither of which you can, in practice, know) the inverse square law really helps you not an iota.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ekahau](http://www.ekahau.com/) specialise on doing this kind of thing with WiFi. You're better off using light to get precision measuring as RF (Radio Frequencies) can be distorted by the environment. There are numerous patents in this area for many of the 'good' solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Not Bluetooth, not Wi-Fi, not GPS and not even ultra wide band (UWB) can reliably achieve this type of accuracy. I'd like to provide you with a solution but it would require very, very sophisticated HW + SW.

Wi-Fi is the most common location technology for indoor enterprise, but even that can go just down to about one meter. To assist Wi-Fi, for example we at Ekahau have "location beacons" that are separate battery-powered transmitters to enhance accuracy further in critical areas. But even they don't really help if you want to measure the distance between two mobile devices within 10cm radius.

UWB boasts "3 feet or better" accuracy, but I wouldn't trust that it goes down to 10cm granularity (plus it's highly expensive and not present in the devices you're tracking).

GPS doesn't really work indoors, and outdoors, like is said before, the accuracy is several meters, not cm.

Bluetooth works over the same frequency as Wi-Fi, and thus has the same accuracy limitations.

Comment: We can use radio waves to determine how close we are to the planet Venus  to an accuracy of centimetres.  I don't understand why a small sensor can't transmit a radio signal to another small sensor, also sitting on my desktop, and get an distance accurate to within a micron.

Answer (score 2):

GPS won't give you 10cm accuracy.  You might get something like on [the order of metres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Error_sources_and_analysis).

It sounds like [Bluetooth can be used](http://www.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~fwinkler/publications/BILS_WPNC04.pdf) for indoor localization, but I am not sure as to the availability of API's and the like to make the job easier.

Comment: Submeter accuracy via GPS is not uncommon these days, especially with differential correction built into higher-end chips.

Comment: GPS-based positioning to within 3-4 cm accuracy via carrier-phase differential GPS has been feasible since the mid-1990s.  A [Stanford helicopter UAV](http://arl.stanford.edu/projects/past-projects/hummingbird "title") used 4 GPS receivers in 1995 to control position with 1 cm accuracy and roll/pitch/yaw to within 1 degree (I believe).  I saw it at the 1995 AUVSI aerial robotics competition; it flew like it was nearly on rails so long as six GPS satellites were in view.

Comment: Yeah but, we're talking about low cost commodity hardware

Answer (score 0):

Getting a precision RF positioning system would be nice, but costly.  Inertial measurements can provide 10cm accuracy.  However, there two issues that make inertial measurement units (IMU) less practical.

1. Error accumulates over time and accuracy degrades.
2. IMU needs to be initialized at a known location.  For example, devices may be physically brought together.

$0.02